# No callback from API after php cURL request

Tags: php, curl

My code makes a curl request to an API that converts image formats e.g. png to jpg.
The API documentation offers a callback from the API which, when the conversion is finished, will send a GET request to a url on my server (hosted, not localhost). I provide this url to the API with the key/value pair: 
`"callback" => "12coins.net/cc_callback.php"`
Unfortunately the API never calls back. Are my curl_setopt parameters wrong or what could be the problem?

```
    $ch_start_process = curl_init();

        $start_process_data = array(
           "callback" => "https://12coins.com/cc_callback.php", 
           "input" => "download", 
           "file" => "https://12coins.com/photo_file.png",//the image I want converted
           "tag" => "tag - unused for now", 
           "outputformat" => "jpg");

        $process_url = "https:".$url_from_create;//prepend https to construct a valid endpoint.
          //$url_from_create is a url returned by the API to a request immediately prior to this one 


        curl_setopt($ch_start_process, CURLOPT_URL, $process_url); 
        curl_setopt($ch_start_process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query ($start_process_data));
        curl_setopt($ch_start_process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch_start_process, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );

        $start_response=curl_exec($ch_start_process);//assign return value of curl_exec()
```

This is the script on my (remote) server `12coins.net/cc_callback.php` to which the API should call back but doesn't:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
echo 'cc_callback has been called';
echo 'The GET request from CloudConvert is: '. $_GET;
?>
```

Comment: Looks like the SSL certificate on your domain 12coins.com appears to be expired/invalid - therefore the api server is not able to call back to your site?

Comment: Open your site in chrome and you'll see the cert error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Latheesan but the domain name is just one I made up. It's not the one I'm actually using. The one I am using has a valid certificate. Also, the API does return the converted image. So there are no issues, I think, other than the API is unable to return data to the callback url on my site.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you tried contacting the API provider?

Answer (score 0):

The API does in fact make a call back. It was just that with the code as shown in cc_callback.php there was no way for me to detect the callback. I had assumed that the echo statements would allow me to see the API's response in the (Chrome) network tab of my brower's dev tools. But of course the echo statements echo to the client that 'called' it with a GET request. In this case, that client is the API and not my browser/html page.

Realising this, I was then easily able to check that it had worked all along by adding
 `mail(myemailaddress@gmail.com, 'This is the url returned to the callback',$GET[url]);` to my php script (shown in the question). This sent me an email when I sent an image to the API for processing and thus confirmed that the API was making the call back..

The curl code in the question is good. It makes a successful request to the API.

Lastly, the curl code is for a request to the CloudConvert API, version 1. There is a version 2 but the code above is not good for that. Also, there's an earlier curl request which must be used in conjunction with the one above which I'll post later for the sake of completeness.